# Overload ambiguity in C++ for automatically converting objects into a "printable" format

Tags: c++, c++14, overloading, sfinae

I'm trying to write a function that takes an input. If that input can be directly piped to a stream (such as with `std::cout <<`), it returns the input unchanged. Otherwise, it attempts to convert the input into a string, and returns the string.

I have the following code:

```
//Uses SFINAE to determine which overload to call
//See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error
//Basically, make_printable detects whether an object can be directly piped to a stream.
//If it can't be piped to a stream, it's converted into a string.
template<typename T, 
        typename StreamT = void, 
        typename = decltype(std::declval<T>().operator std::string())>
std::string make_printable(const T& obj) {
    std::cout << "[std::string make_printable(obj)]";
    return (std::string)obj;
}

template<
        typename T, 
        typename StreamT = std::ostream,
        typename = decltype(std::declval<StreamT&>() << std::declval<T const &>())>
const T& make_printable(const T& obj) {
    std::cout << "[const T& make_printable(obj)]";
    return obj;
}
```

This code works when called on objects that can *either* be converted into a string, *or* can be written to a stream, but if I have an object that can *both* be converted into a string and written to a stream, the code fails due to ambiguity in terms of which function to call.

How can I rewrite these functions, or resolve this ambiguity, so that objects which can be both converted into a string and written to a stream are output as-is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I rewrite these functions, or resolve this ambiguity, so that objects which can be both converted into a string and written to a stream are output as-is?

If you can add a level of indirection, a possible way is use a preferred overloading.

I mean... if you add an unused `int` argument for the preferred version and a `long` one for the other

```
template<typename T, 
        typename StreamT = void, 
        typename = decltype(std::declval<T>().operator std::string())>
std::string make_printable (T const & obj, long)
 {                                     //  ^^^^ <-- long argument
   std::cout << "[std::string make_printable(obj)]";
   return (std::string)obj;
 }

template<
        typename T, 
        typename StreamT = std::ostream,
        typename = decltype(std::declval<StreamT&>() << std::declval<T const &>())>
T const & make_printable (T const & obj, int)
 {                                    // ^^^ <-- int argument
   std::cout << "[const T& make_printable(obj)]";
   return obj;
 }
```

and if you add a upper level `make_printable()` that receive the value and pass it with an `int`

```
template <typename T>
auto make_printable (T const & obj)
 { return make_printable(obj, 0); }
```

when both lower level version are available the second one is preferred because a `int` is a better match for a `int` than a `long`.

When only one lower lever version is available, it's called without problems.

En passant: using the good old `auto ... -> decltype()` way to express the return type, SFINAE can be applied to your function in the following way

```
template <typename T>
auto make_printable (T const & obj, long)
   -> decltype( obj.operator std::string() )
 {
   std::cout << "[std::string make_printable(obj)]";
   return (std::string)obj;
 }
template <typename T, typename StreamT = std::ostream>
auto make_printable (T const & obj, int)
   -> decltype( std::declval<StreamT>() << obj , obj )
 {
   std::cout << "[const T& make_printable(obj)]";
   return obj;
 }
```

I suppose it's a question of personal taste but I find this way a little simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to write one function for the stream case and one for everything else.  The latter function can assume a string conversion, or can test for it with more SFINAE.  (The correct test for that is `std::string(std::declval<T>())`; there’s no reason to restrict it to conversion operators.)

But you can’t just drop the SFINAE from your `string` overload, because it would still be the case that neither function is more specialized.  And there’s no *structural* restriction (*i.e.*, deducible) that you can put on the template parameter in the stream overload to make it more specialized.

As always, the answer is partial specialization: because default template arguments are added *before* doing template deduction to select a partial specialization, we can use them for SFINAE:

```
template<class T,class=std::ostream&>
struct printable {
  std::string make(const T& obj) {
    std::cout << "[std::string make_printable(obj)]";
    return (std::string)obj;
  }
};

template<typename T>
struct printable<T,decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T const &>())> {
  const T& make(const T& obj) {
    std::cout << "[const T& make_printable(obj)]";
    return obj;
  }
};

template<class T>
auto make_printable(const T &t)
{return printable<T>::make(t);}
```

The wrapper function serves the usual purposes of a single name and template deduction (again).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper class to convert the validity of `std::declval<StreamT&>() << std::declval<T const &>()` to a constant bool type, e.g.

```
template <typename T, 
          typename StreamT, 
          typename = void>
struct Can_output_directly : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, 
          typename StreamT>
struct Can_output_directly<T, StreamT, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<StreamT&>() << std::declval<T const &>())>> : std::true_type {};
                                    // ^^^^^^^^^^^ C++17 feature
```

Then you can add a template parameter in the first `make_printable`:

```
template <typename T, 
          typename StreamT = std::ostream, // void -> std::ostream
          typename = decltype(std::declval<T>().operator std::string()),
          typename std::enable_if<!Can_output_directly<T, StreamT>::value, int>::type = 0> // note this parameter
std::string make_printable(const T& obj) {
    std::cout << "[std::string make_printable(obj)]";
    return (std::string)obj;
}
```

Now this function template is enabled only if `Can_output_directly<T, StreamT>::value` is `false`, i.e. the second function template is not enabled.